# How do I add a crosshair guide to a FCPX angle editor viewer window?

Tags: video, editing, plugins, final-cut-pro-x

I need to keyframe the Y position transform of a moving subject to keep her in the center of the frame and would like a set of crosshairs to help me do it.  I've seen solutions which employ Motion titles, but I can't get this to work because the clip I'm translating is inside a multicam clip. I've looked, but cannot find, plugins to add this functionality. Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with FCPX however in Vegas Pro there is a button to add a grid to the preview, do you see any such button near your preview screen? Yes, I know a grid is overkill, but at least you would get a crosshair out of it.

Comment: We've got a title safe/ action safe overlay in the dropdown switch next to the viewer, but there are no other options for other types of overlays afaik.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed impossible to put a title over a clip inside a multi cam clip... Unless you turn that clip into a compound clip. Then you can add whatever overlay you want to it.

So you will have:

- keyframed clip with crosshair overlay
- inside a compound clip
- inside a multicam clip

Just right click your the clip inside your multicam clip and choose New Compound Clip ( <kbd>⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>G</kbd> )

Answer (score 0):

The best workflow I've found so far is pulling the left and right edges of the viewer frame inward to isolate the center of the picture.  This is obviously far from ideal.